How to find magnitude of k (wave vector) in hexagonal lattice cell(graphene)?
I want to calculate magnitude of k point(in Brillouin zone) of graphene which has hexagonal unit cell. The lattice parameters of graphene are given below:
 &CONTROL
     calculation = 'scf'
     /
     &SYSTEM
                 ibrav = 4
                     a = 2.46639
                     c = 18
    ATOMIC_SPECIES
    C 12.0107 C.upf
    ATOMIC_POSITIONS (crystal)
    C  0.333333333  0.666666666  0.000000000
    C  0.666666666  0.333333333  0.000000000
    K_POINTS (automatic)
    35 35 1 0 0 0

ibrav 4 has following lattice vectors.

If I open the scf.out and choose a k point (as follows)
cart. coord. in units 2pi/alat  
k(   44) = (   0.3000000   0.5773503   0.0000000), wk =   0.0300000

How can I calculate the magnitude of the |k| in the hexagonal reciprocal unit cell? considering that I know the value of (kx, ky, 0). The lattice is a parallelogram so that |k| does NOT simply equal to sqrt(kx^2+ky^2), right?

You want to compute the norm and you can simply do that on the k-vectors in Cartesian coordinates. This has nothing to do with the underlying crystal symmetry. If your k-vectors are given relative to the reciprocal lattice vectors (in QE they call these units reduced) you have to first bring the k-vectors back to the Cartesian coordinate system in order to get a meaningful norm.
